# PhantomJS compile with WebGL

Tags: qt, webgl, phantomjs, qtwebkit

I am trying to compile PhantomJS to add WebGL. Apparently it is possible because of:

- [post on groups.google.com](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phantomjs/yagAkrYl6eg/rltehGAyt9QJ)
- [post on trac.webkit.org](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKitWebGL)

However, I have no idea how to do this. I have looked in all the configuration for compiling and I tried and found nothing.
Should I compile QTWebKit separately with the necessary options and then compile PhantomJS with this WebKit?
I'm on Mac OSX Lion.

It would be really nice to have a bit of help.

Comment: I have dug a little bit and found that I needed to compile with OpenGL (did this by removing QT_CFG+=' -no-opengl' from `src/qt/preconfig.sh`) and ENABLE_WEBGL in the webkit config.
However after this I noticed that some part of the Qt source were absent (opengl for eg). I replaced the source with Qt 4.8.4 but I still get compilation errors. I must be missing something any ideas?

Comment: I have FTM worked around this by using Canvas instead of WebGL but the performances are obviously not as good so I'm still interested by your answers

Comment: If you don't have any other requirements (unlikely) consider [slimerjs](http://slimerjs.org/features.html) which is similar but Gecko/Mozilla FF based and supports WebGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you well may know, Phantomjs has is no longer being actively developed.

I suggest you move to Puppeteer which uses Chromium: https://pptr.dev/

Answer (score 0):

This was opened by [ariya](https://github.com/ariya) who also commented on the Google Groups thread as a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10273).

According to this [comment by a project collaborator](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10273#issuecomment-167819677) on that issue:

> That's not that easy. WebGL requires OpenGL. OpenGL requires XCB on Linux. That means that you will not be able to use PhantomJS in full headless environment. I doubt that this will be implemented in near future.

It seems to me like this is the final answer to the OP's question. The OP has not addressed whether [SlimerJS](https://slimerjs.org/index.html) would actually work in their situation.